# Google+ sign in: PlusClient VS AccountManager

Tags: android, google-plus

I am building an Android application which needs a Google+ Sign in functionality.
This is needed to identify the user and to get access to the user's friends/contacts in Google+.
I can see two options to build the login flow: using android.accounts.AccountManager or using com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient.

Which one is the preferred approach to execute the single-button-click login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient is the recommended approach:

According to [Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/)

> If you are planning to provide a “sign-in with Google” feature, we recommend using Google+ Sign-in, which provides the OAuth 2.0 authentication mechanism along with additional access to Google desktop and mobile features.

Comment: And do you know the difference between AccountMgr approach vs. using the PlusClient?

Comment: PlusClient  provides a  way to let people use their Google credentials to sign-in to your client.  


AccountMgr on the other hand lets people use their online service credentials (not necessarily Google) to sign-in to your client